# Magento 2 Angular js error while run setup

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, setup

I am new to Magento, I am trying to set up Magento with ddev. So, Downloaded setup version 2.3 with sample data. When I run the setup it shows AngularJs errors in the console (See the screenshot).

[image]

Also, it hangs the chrome tab, needs to restart the browser.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe redirect the issue. I face that issue for the wrong Nginx config issue.

Try using the command line:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://magento2.com/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=root \
--admin-firstname=FName --admin-lastname=LName --admin-email=youremil@mail.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

You need to modify DB user/pass, base_url, admin user/pass from the above command.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried CLI installation but getting this [error](https://prnt.sc/rssmli)

Comment: What is the error?